# Angular Script not running when page is reopened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

This is the first website I have ever made: http://moneyforkids.ca/old

And I am having a problem that I cannot seem to figure out.

If you visit the certificate page, you should be able to type your name onto the certificate. However, if you click on a different tab and then come back to the certificate tab, you are unable to type your name on the certificate. Instead you just see {{ name }} in the middle of it, which tells me the angular script is not running.

Here's my code that executes the angular script: http://moneyforkids.ca/old/js/index.js

EDIT: 
I achieved the expected behaviour by changing the index.js file to :

```
$( function() {

$('nav a').on('click', function(e) {                 // User clicks nav link
  e.preventDefault();                                // Stop loading new link
  var url = this.href;                               // Get value of href

  $('nav a.current').removeClass('current');         // Clear current indicator
  $(this).addClass('current');                       // New current indicator

  $('#content').remove(); 
  $('#container').load(url + " #content").hide().fadeIn('slow'); // Load content with AJAX



  if (url.slice(-13) == "practice.html") {
    $.getScript("js/practice.js");
    $.getScript("js/ui-spinner-behaviour.js");

  } else if (url.slice(-16) == "certificate.html") {
    $.getScript("js/certificate.js");
    $.getScript("js/ui-spinner-behaviour.js");
    $('#angular').remove(); //Remove any previous angular script tag
    $('<script id="angular" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>').insertAfter('section'); // Reload the script
  } else {
        $.getScript("js/repeatPictures.js");
  }
}); 
})
```

The updated .js file above fixed the website. You can see the new version of the website without the problem by removing the /old at end of website address (I can't post more than 2 links).

However, I don't understand why this fixes the problem!

Comment: Console is showing that you are trying to load angular more than once.
Check if you are loading angular more than one time or not. Otherwise show us your code where you are loading angular library and the dependency injection portion.

Comment: The index.js (http://moneyforkids.ca/js/index.js) file is what injects angular. And I guess when the certificate tab is clicked for a second time, angular gets confused because it was already loaded onto the page. But the page content was changed through AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

it's not angular got confused it's your code. you are loading angular on click then you need to check on second click if angular is loaded then just don't load it again. If you notice when you click one time on Certificate tab there is no `**{{name}}**`  but next time you click the tab again and then angular break down and you see `**{{name}}**`

Comment: So I only load angular once now, it does not give an error. However, {{ name }} still shows up on second time visiting certificate tab. You can see this behaviour at http://moneyforkids.ca/old. I fixed the problem on http://moneyforkids.ca but I am not sure why getting rid of the $.getScript tag fixed the angular script. You can see the code for injecting angular on both  versions of the site by by going to http://moneyforkids.ca/js/index.js and http://moneyforkids.ca/old/js/index.js